How to add extra column in Role model in apache superset
I am trying to extend Role model of apache superset and add channel_id as extra column. I have done it through superset_config.py and it looks like this.
import flask_appbuilder.const as c
import logging
from werkzeug.security import generate_password_hash
from superset.security import SupersetSecurityManager
logging.getLogger("alembic").addHandler(logging.NullHandler())
log = logging.getLogger(__name__)


from flask_appbuilder.security.sqla.models import User, Role
from sqlalchemy import (
    Column,
    Integer,
)

from flask_appbuilder.security.views import UserDBModelView, AuthDBView
from flask_appbuilder.security.views import UserDBModelView, expose, RoleModelView
from flask_appbuilder.security.decorators import has_access
from flask import redirect, g, flash, request
from typing import Any
from sqlalchemy.orm.query import Query
from flask_appbuilder.models.sqla.filters import BaseFilter
from flask_login import login_user, logout_user

class CustomUser(User):
    def __init__(self):
        super(CustomUser, self).__init__()

    __tablename__ = "ab_user"
    channel_id = Column(Integer)

    def get_channel_id(self):
        return self.channel_id


class CustomRole(Role):
    def __init__(self):
        super(CustomRole, self).__init__()

    __tablename__ = "ab_role"
    channel_id = Column(Integer)

  
SECRET_KEY = SECRET_KEY

class CustomSecurityManager(SupersetSecurityManager):
    user_model = CustomUser
    role_model = CustomRole

    def update_custom_filter(self):
        from typing import Any
        from sqlalchemy.orm.query import Query
        from superset.views.base import BaseFilter

    def __init__(self, appbuilder):
        super(CustomSecurityManager, self).__init__(appbuilder)

    def add_user(
            self,
            username,
            first_name,
            last_name,
            email,
            role,
            password="",
            hashed_password="",
            channel_id=0
    ):
        """
        Generic function to create user
        """
        try:
            user = self.user_model()
            user.first_name = first_name
            user.last_name = last_name
            user.username = username
            user.email = email
            user.active = True
            user.channel_id = channel_id
            user.roles = role if isinstance(role, list) else [role]
            if hashed_password:
                user.password = hashed_password
            else:
                user.password = generate_password_hash(password)
            # user.save()
            # self.appbuilder.get_session
            self.get_session.add(user)
            id = self.get_session.commit()
            log.info(c.LOGMSG_INF_SEC_ADD_USER, username)
            return user
        except Exception as e:
            log.error(c.LOGMSG_ERR_SEC_ADD_USER, e)
            return False


CUSTOM_SECURITY_MANAGER = CustomSecurityManager

so when I am running docker container using docker run after docker build command I am getting this error during this step:

docker build -t supers . (working fine)
docker run -d -p 8080:8088 -e "SUPERSET_SECRET_KEY=actual key" --name superdash supers

In docker

docker run

Getting this error at this step:
Init Step 2/4 [Starting] -- Setting up admin user ( admin / admin ):
No user created an error occured
ERROR:superset_config:Error adding new user to database. Attempting to flush an item of type <class 'superset_config.CustomRole'> as a member of collection "User.roles". Expected an object of type <class 'flask_appbuilder.security.sqla.models.Role'> or a polymorphic subclass of this type. If <class 'superset_config.CustomRole'> is a subclass of <class 'flask_appbuilder.security.sqla.models.Role'>, configure mapper "mapped class Role->ab_role" to load this subtype polymorphically, or set enable_typechecks=False to allow any subtype to be accepted for flush. 

